Cross section along the single transmission path of electron
I am studying this  research paper "Forecasting of ionospheric vertical total electron content (TEC) using LSTM networks" about ionosphere, but in introduction section I phrase I didn't understand:

The ionosphere is an important space environment
near the earth. Its disturbance can cause severe propagation
effects to radio information system, especially during
ionospheric storm, thus influencing radio information
system negatively, such as communication, navigation,
radar and so on.  Total electron content (TEC) is an
important parameter to describe the properties of ionosphere, and it is directly related to propagation effects, so TEC forecast is important in scientific research. TEC is defined by the integral of electron density in a column of
$1$ $m^2$ cross section along the single transmission path.

My question is that what does mean of "column of $1$ $m^2$ cross section"? Anybody help me to give simple explanation because I am computer science student, I have zero knowledge in physics.

My guess is that "single transmission path" is a typo, and should be "signal transmission path".  Also, "column" is likely better phrased as something like "tube".

@BaddDadd would you explain what does mean of $1$ $m^2?$

The 1 m^2 just means the tube has a cross sectional area of 1 square meter.  It doesn't matter if it's a square tube or a round tube, because the density variation isn't known to that accuracy.  So if your signal path is 10 km long, it has a volume of 10,000 cubic meters.
